# What is the connection between fasting and mourning that the bridegroom is no longer with the disciples?

Tags: matthew, fasting

> 14At that time John’s disciples came to Jesus and asked, “Why is it that we and the Pharisees **fast** so often, but ***Your disciples*** **do not fast**?”
> 15 Jesus replied, “How can the *guests of the bridegroom* **mourn** while **He is with them**? But the time will come when ***the bridegroom*** **will be taken from them**; ***then they will fast***. Matthew 9

What is the connection between fasting and having Jesus taken from the disciples?

Comment: Everything has a season, like wise King Salomon once wrote. Although not completely boxed in, feasting is for celebrating Jesus birth and to copy the gift-giving of the magi, at Christmas. While, fasting is to celebrate Jesus’ crucifixion, death and resurrection of Easter.

Answer (score 2):

Matthew 9:

> 15 Jesus replied, “How can the guests of the **bridegroom** mourn while **He** is with them? But the time will come when the bridegroom will be taken from them; then they will fast.

Jesus referred to himself as the bridegroom as John the Baptizer did in John 3:

> 29 The bride belongs to the **bridegroom**. The friend who attends the bridegroom waits and listens for him, and is full of joy when he hears the bridegroom’s voice. That joy is mine, and it is now complete.

When Jesus was taken away from his disciples, then they would mourn and fast.

Answer (score 0):

**Bachelor's Party** To use a modern metaphor, just before a wedding, all the groom's men and bachelor friends get together and have a party celebrating and signifying the transition of a single person going into a marriage covenant! It is not a time of sadness or restraint from rejoicing, but a gay old time of frivolity and happiness.

After the party---and after the wedding---things go back to normal, every day living with its stress and efforts.

**So also** So also, Jesus, the celebrated Divine Bridegroom (of the Church bride; see Ephesians 5) was fellowshipping with the disciples and Apostles. They were having a blessed time in the Presence of Jesus, who was sharing His teaching and insights with them, as well as telling them of the awesome future the Church would experience in the amazing Kingdom of God.

But this would not last much longer.  Jesus knew He would be crucified, resurrected, coronated, and **Ascended back to heaven**.  He would be leaving the earth---and them---soon. And then, the Disciples would be left alone to continue living on earth with all its challenges, disciplines, and rigors of spreading the Gospel in a pagan world with its persecutions.

At that time, the Disciples would resort to **much prayer and fasting** and supplications to God for the needed Anointing of the Holy Spirit to live the Christian life. Fastings and earnest prayers (with weeping and tears of compassion) are normal parts of the Christian life. Christians were to live this holy style of life until the End and Second Coming, when the Church of Christ would see Jesus again and partake in the "marriage supper of the Lamb!"

The **Fasting** mentioned by Jesus was merely a reference to one of the normal practices within Christian living, that they would be doing *after Jesus Ascended*.  But for now, they were in the Presence of the Holy Messiah.  They were basking in the Glory of His Presence. Rejoicing was in order!!!

Answer (score 0):

When we are longing for Christ we fast. When they are apart the bride longs for the bridegroom to return. Fasting represents our longing for Christ to come back.

In the 16th century, John Calvin said,

> Let us say something about fasting, because many, for want of knowing
> its usefulness, undervalue its necessity, and some reject it as almost
> superfluous; while, on the other hand where the use of it is not well
> understood, it easily degenerates into superstition. Holy and
> legitimate fasting is directed to three ends; for we practice it
> either as a **restraint on the flesh**, to preserve it from
> licentiousness, or as a **preparation for prayers and pious meditations**,
> or **as a testimony of our humiliation in the presence of God when we
> are desirous of confessing our guilt before him.** (Institutes, IV.12,
> 14, 15)

The meal doesn't begin until both the bride and bridegroom are present. So until then, we show by fasting that we are waiting for His return. Praying for His return and waiting to confess before Him. Until He returns we will mourn His for His presence and fast.